# get text content when row is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, layout-inflater

I'm searching for some way to get text from view when the row is clicked

I have using layout inflater with list adapter , but I was filed to solve this problem.

I was trying to use :

```
    public class LastDaysAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LastDaysHelper>{


    private final Activity activity;
     List<LastDaysHelper> busIDs = new ArrayList<LastDaysHelper>();
     List<LastDaysHelper> Dates = new ArrayList<LastDaysHelper>();
    Context context;

    public LastDaysAdapter(Activity activity,List<LastDaysHelper> list, Context context2, List<LastDaysHelper> list2){
        super(activity, R.layout.activity_last_days,list );
        this.activity=activity;
        this.busIDs=list;
        this.Dates=list2;
        this.context=context2;
    }


    class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView palteNumber;
        protected TextView LastDate;
        protected TableRow row;
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rep, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();


            viewHolder.palteNumber = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

            viewHolder.LastDate = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView2);  



            viewHolder.row = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.TableRow05);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.row.setTag(busIDs.get(position));



        } else{
            view = convertView;


            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).row.setTag(busIDs
                    .get(position));

        }


        final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();


        holder.palteNumber.setText(busIDs.get(position).getDate());

        holder.LastDate.setText(Dates.get(position).getDate());
        return view;
}
}
```

Edit i have try to use this :

```
 public class LastDaysActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_last_days);
    final Button newFourm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    LastDaysAdapter adapter = new LastDaysAdapter(this, getDates(),
            getApplicationContext(), getBusID());

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    newFourm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LastDaysActivity.this,
                    TabHostActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public List<LastDaysHelper> getDates() {

    final MySQLiteHelper my = new MySQLiteHelper(LastDaysActivity.this);

    return my.getDates();

}

public List<LastDaysHelper> getBusID() {

    final MySQLiteHelper my = new MySQLiteHelper(LastDaysActivity.this);

    return my.getBuses();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

My apolgies.  Originally you didn't include the ListActivity and I didn't notice it when you edited.

Do this:

1)  Get rid of the setOnClickListner();
2)  in your change your @Override onListItemClick to:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    TextView myView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.{id_of_your_text_view});
    String text = myView.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, text + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: i can't understand , where i shuold use onItemClick ?? , after else statement ?

Comment: btw good tutorial on this:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#androidlists_adapterintro

Comment: Also just fixed a mistyped variable name.

Comment: Sorry the new ListView() line was just an example, whatever view you were previously applying your adapter to is what you should apply the click listener to.  What you have edited in doesn't work for a number of reasons, the most basic of which is that the listView you created isn't attached to a parent view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47797/discussion-between-nathaniel-waggoner-and-user3245658)

Comment: Sorry didn't realize this was a listActivity.  One moment.

Comment: i have clicked on the row but toast message not appear , i'm using background fot rep.xml , but when i press on above it's background it works . why ?